# How do I center the nav items in the collapsable menu nav

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the nav-items text in the collapsable menu ,

but for some reason when I select .nav-item in css , with text-align
center , it doesn't work ,

what am I doing wrong ? I've also tried doing text-align on .navbar-nav  but it still doesn't center the text ?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-item-logout {
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        right: 0;
        font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: rgb(223, 250, 250);
        padding: 5px;
        width: 25%; 
    }


    .menu {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        float: right;
        top: 10px;
        position: relative;

    }
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark large_navbar">
        <div class="container1">
      <a class="navbar-brand ml-4 mr-4" href="#"><b>Future Sounds</b></a>
    <button class="menu" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" onclick="this.classList.toggle('opened');this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', this.classList.contains('opened'))" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path class="line line1" d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058" />
        <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80" />
        <path class="line line3" d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942" />
      </svg>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu_nav" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'home' %}">HOME</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'users_list' %}">ADD NEW FRIENDS</a>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'friend_list' %}">FRIENDS</a> 
            <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'my_profile' %}">PROFILE</a> 
            <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">CREATE POST</a>
            <a class="nav-item-logout auth_buttons btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'logout' %}">LOGOUT</a>
          {% else %}
            <a class="nav-item auth_buttons btn btn-success  text-light" href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a>
            <a class="nav-item auth_buttons btn btn-info text-light" href="{% url 'register' %} ">REGISTER</a>
          {% endif %}
            {% block searchform %}{% endblock searchform %}
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>

    <footer class="page-footer font-small black">
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">Future Sounds © 2020
      <br><small class="text-muted">All rights reserved!</small>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Look in the dev console and see if there is some Bootstrap CSS over-riding your CSS.

Comment: Without a working example, it's hard to see where the issue is.

Comment: I think it might be bootstrap over-riding my command , how can I override the bootstrap css ?

Comment: Make your CSS more specific. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Your screen width set as android's

Answer (score 0):

What about extend the container1 on the entire page (`<div class="container1 w-100">`) and then center your menu_nav (`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu_nav w-100 d-flex justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">`)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem , it was another .nav-item command I had in css , where I had set the width to 25%, I changed this to 100% and now I'm able to center the nav-item links